# RDP into PC with VPN

Tags: windows, rdp, cisco-vpn

I have a work PC (Win 7 Ent) (usually given to me by my clients) where I do work related projects and a home PC (Win 10 Pro) where I do my freelancing stuff. 
Both are connected to my home network.

Usually I just RDP from home PC to the work one, spawn the screen across all my three 27" monitors and work happily.

But now, I've got a work PC where I must use VPN to access some of the client's internal resources. The VPN client is `Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, v.4.3.01095`.

Once VPN connects I cannot RDP anymore from my home PC, even though we are in the same local home network. I can ping it using local IP, but RDP won't connect.

Is there a solution for this? There is no way the client will change any settings on the Cisco server. All I can do is tweak the work PC only.

Please advise.

Comment: I also tried to use ngrok to create a tcp tunnel on port 3389, and it gets created fine, but RDP won't connect to address that ngrok is showing. Right now I can remote into work PC only via TeamViewer or SplashTop, but none of them allow to expand the screen as RDP does.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a 2nd network card to the work PC, assign a static IP address in a different network and connect that way?

Comment: No, the work PC is a laptop actually. Unless I can buy an USB network card. The question is, to what network shall I assign it?
I only have one home network though.

Comment: You could pick a completely random network, for example 10.1.50.0 and a subnet of 255.255.255.0.  You wouldn't need a gateway as that traffic is only between your PC and the work laptop.

Comment: are you saying just to hardlink the 2 computers between them using a network cable? This might not work, as sometimes the Home PC (which is a laptop as well) is not in the home network, then I need to RDP from internet. (port forwarding is all setup on the router)

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer is somewhat complex and layed out here: https://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn

tl;dr AnyConnect is bulls*t, it messes with the local routing table. Use other VPN-Client software to create the tunnel. For example try [Shrew](https://www.shrew.net/download) to import the cisco profile and connect to your endpoint. Works perfect for me and is a lot more stable.

Comment: Shrew looks like wasn't updated for past couple of years. Is it still ok? :)

Comment: For me it is ... AnyConnect is still the same, even when installed through the store.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me, as the Cisco client is configured to use certificates which are configured with a non-exportable private key. No luck here, unless there a way to import the connection profile from Cisco directly into Shrew, which I could not find.

Answer (score 0):

You need to the client with the VPN to enable split-tunneling on their Firewall so you can RDP to your work machine at the same time as your on the VPN.

[Here is a link on how to enable Split-tunneling on a Cisco ASA.](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/70917-asa-split-tunnel-vpn-client.html)